# Root Verizon Samsung Galaxy Note 3 4.4.2 without tripping Knox

Tags: rooting, root-access, 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-note-3, cyanogenmod

I have been searching and searching for a way to root my Verizon Samsung galaxy note 3 with 4.4.2 on it and with out tripping kknox, and am very unlucky. I have heard of Root_de_LA_Vega and it tripping Knox with 4.4.2. Then there is TowelRoot, this I feel might work, so if anyone has the same phone with the same update and has tried it. Tell me how it worked out. The last option I have found being cyangen mod installer. Once again if anyone has tried it on the same phone, tell me how it worked out.

Any feed back is great and thank you in advance.

Comment: No it doesn't I have an unlocked note 3. Did towelroot... And it failed said that device Aint supported yet...